# how to design User Interface compatible with any screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I fear of User Interface (UI) programming, so I always stand away from doing UI design. I think that UI design is like art and it makes me nervous.

Unfortunately, I had faced to do UI design in my company. I had no choice to work other. My manager assigned me to draw logo design and to make UI design for the whole website. As you know, I want to die for a while in that time.

I have a motto ; "**Think Positive, Do Positive, Hope Positive and then Be Positive**". :)
So, I decided to do my best in any situation, whatever difficulties ahead.

My boyfriend and my friends gave me many supports while I was doing that project. Because of their support,
now I'm interesting in UI design.

I want to learn how to design User Interface compatible with any screen size. Pls give me some suggestions for me.

Thanks to all !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a UI framework.

A great framework for responsive websites (websites that work on any screen size including mobile) is Twitter **Boostrap**.

http://getbootstrap.com/

It really makes UI design very easy and professional looking.

There are other frameworks too such as:

http://foundation.zurb.com/

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Just search google for "UI frameworks"

Comment: Thanks @geo1701, I am a beginner in UI design. My customers request to run their websites in IE 10, 9. So, I don't know that bootstrap is compatible in IE.

Comment: Its compatible with all major browsers including IE8, 9 & 10. It also works on iPhone, Android & Windows phone too :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to learn how to design User Interface compatible with any screen size

One of the most important modern ***concepts*** for UI design, that solves the obstacle of various screen sizes, is **[Responsive Design](http://responsivedesign.ca/)**. The idea that the UI is not static or rigid, but refactors or responds to different resolutions and actually adapts or appears differently based on that.

A valuable ***skill*** you could put into practice is **[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**. They allow you to target different resolutions directly in CSS and fit your UI to different devices (for example, phone vs tablet vs desktop).

Lastly, if you want an entire ***template*** that will work as a starting point for a responsive UI, look into the **[Bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/).** This will give you working examples that you can build on and see the Responsive Design and Media Queries in action.

Comment: Thanks @sweeds, I heard the Bootstrap framework is very useful for UI design but I have no experience in that framework until now. Thanks for your suggestion.